# Stop mesh from continously recreating UVmaps?

Tags: uv, sculpting

So I'm sculpting a character, and I usually start from a cube, which by default has a UVmap. This gets in the way of dynamic topology, which will disable itself if it detects a UVmap.

My issue is, after deleting a UVmap, I will be sculpting, and randomly, it will make another UVmap. I delete it, and soon it will make another.

How can I stop this from happening?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This issue shows itself usually when you start sculpting with the default cube, as that one comes like all other default mesh objects by default with UVs already.
[image]

After deleting the UV-Map once, you can start sculpting without the problem, but should you by chance use **undo** <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>Z</kbd> often enough, when sculpting early on and go back enough to **undo** the deletion of the UV-map, it will start bothering you again.

The easier solution would be to delete the default cube and then add a new one, **with** but one change. After you added the cube, open the options given and deactivate the **Generate UVs**.
[image]
*changing the option will affect the new cube*

This way should you start sculpting and use **undo**, well rather then getting the UVs back, you would undo the cube, which would be obvious.

My tip here would be to save after adding the cube without UVs and loading the file anew.
From there you can undo to your hearts content and will be fine.

Happy Blending

Comment: Thankyou! Yeah I usually start from a default file, so I can just save that one as the startup file.